# Poor response when parameters are variables in sql udf

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Have an inline sql udf
When called with variable

```
DECLARE @COMNO CHAR(3), @CUNO VARCHAR(6)
SELECT @COMNO='020',@CUNO ='000022'
select * from ftItemsOfCustomer(@COMNO,@CUNO)
```

TAKES 9 SECONDS,
WHERE AS

```
select * from ftItemsOfCustomer'020','000022')
```

TAKES ONLY A SECOND !

- WHY AND HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS TO
  PERFORM WITH EQUAL RESPONSE TIME WHEN
  VARIABLES USED INSTEAD OF LITERALS

Here is the function..

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ftItemsOfCustomer]    Script Date: 02/24/2010 10:23:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--
--ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ftItemsOfCustomer](@COMNO CHAR(3),@T$CUNO CHAR(6)) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
--/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @t$cuno char(6),@comno char(3),@ovrideQtyDisc bit;select @t$cuno='000022',@comno='020',@ovrideQtyDisc=1;
select @t$cuno='000310',@comno='020'
select @t$cuno='200252'
select @t$cuno='000680'
--select @t$cuno='000694'
--SELECT T$CPLS FROM TTCCOM010NNN WHERE T$CUNO=@T$cuno and comno=@comno

-- 1 Customer /item discount---------(30)
-- 2 customer / pricegroup/discount--(31)
-- 3 customer /discount -------------(31)
-- 4 price list /item            ----(32) -- no discount here only list pirce and pricelist
-- 5 pricelist /price group/discount-(33)
-- 6 pricelist /discount-------------(33)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
--1). 030 CUSTOMER AND ITEM FOR DISCOUNT  
--2). 031 CUSTOMER AND PRICEGROUP
--3). 031 Customer only - blanket - not implemented (as of 24th Feb 2010)
--4). 033 PRICELIST and priceGroup
--5). 033 pricelist and priceGroup=null

--1) 33 for Discounts via cpgs          DISCOUNT (G) 33g.t$cpgs = itm.cpgs and 33g.t$cpls=
--2) 32 for price List & item for       DISCOUNT (P)
--3) 32 for item (no Price List) for    PRICE    (I)
--4) 30 for customer & Item For         DISCOUNT (C)
-- Discount prescedance 1=C, 2=P ,3=G
SELECT  distinct 
        ItemCode            =   P.T$ITEM
        ,UPC_Code           =   U.UPC   
        ,Description        =   U.t$dsca
        ,ciDesc             =   T.t$dsca
        ,ListPrice          =   I.t$Pric
        ,Multiplier         =   Isnull(convert(decimal(6,4),1.0000-(COALESCE(NULLIF(C.T$DISC,0.000),NULLIF(CPG.T$DISC,0.000),NULLIF(P.T$DISC,0.000),NULLIF(G.T$DISC,0.000),NULLIF(NOPG.T$DISC,0.000))/100.000)),1.000)
        --,NetPrice         =   Round(I.t$pric*Convert(decimal(10,3),1.00-(COALESCE(NULLIF(C.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(P.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(G.T$DISC,0.00))/100.00)),0)
        ,NetPrice           =   Convert(decimal(10,2),Round(I.t$pric*Isnull(Convert(decimal(10,4),1.00-(COALESCE(NULLIF(C.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(CPG.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(P.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(G.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(NOPG.T$DISC,0.00))/100.00)),1),2))
        ,ShippingIndicator  =   U.T$ship
        ,Weight             =   T.t$wght
        ,t$cpgs             =   T.t$cpgs
        ,GDISC=G.t$dISC
        ,Discount           =   COALESCE(NULLIF(C.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(CPG.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(P.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(G.T$DISC,0.00))
        ,Gdisc              =   g.t$disc
        ,pdisc              =   p.t$disc
        ,cdisc              =   c.t$disc
        ,cpgDisc            =   cpg.t$disc
        ,DiscountSource     =   CASE COALESCE(NULLIF(C.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(CPG.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(P.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(G.T$DISC,0.00),NULLIF(noPg.T$disc,0.0))    
                                    WHEN C.T$DISC       THEN 'Disc(30)[cuno,item]'
                                    WHEN P.T$DISC       THEN 'DISC(32)[CPGS]'
                                    WHEN G.T$DISC       THEN 'DISC(33)[CPLS,CPGS]'
                                    WHEN NOPG.T$DISC    THEN 'DISC(33)[CPLS]'
                                    WHEN CPG.T$DISC     THEN 'DISC(31)'
                                    ELSE '?'
                                END

        ,cpls               =   P.t$cpls
        ,t$QANP             =   P.t$QANP
        ,Ccuno              =   com.t$cuno
        ,noPg.*
        FROM        TTCCOM010nnn        COM WITH (iNdex(IX_COMNO_TTCCOM010NNN)) 
        JOIN        TTDSLS032nnn        P   WITH (INDEX(IX_T$CPLS_TTDSLS032NNN)) ON P.T$CPLS    =   COM.T$CPLS  
        JOIN        TTDSLS032nnn        I   WITH (INDEX(IX_T$ITEM_TTDSLS032NNN),INDEX(IX_COMNO_TTDSLS032NNN)) ON    I.t$item    =   P.t$item    
                                        AND i.comno         =   p.comno 
                                        AND 1               =   dbo.fnIsDateInRange(i.t$stdt,i.t$tdat) 
                                        AND i.t$cpls        =   ''
LEFT    JOIN        TTDSLS030nnn        C  WITH (INDEX(IX_T$ITEM_TTDSLS030NNN),INDEX(IX_COMNO_TTDSLS030NNN))    ON  c.t$item    =   i.t$Item    
                                        AND c.Comno         =   i.comno AND c.t$cuno    =   @t$cuno
                                        AND 1               =   dbo.fnIsDateInRange(c.t$stdt,c.t$tdat)  
        JOIN        TTIITM001nnn        T       WITH(INDEX(IX_T$ITEM_TTIITM001nnn),INDEX(IX_COMNO_TTIITM001NNN)) on t.t$item    =   p.T$item    AND t.comno     =   p.Comno
LEFT    JOIN        TTDSLS033nnn        G       WITH(INDEX(IX_T$CPGS_TTDSLS033NNN)) ON  G.t$CPGS    =   T.T$CPGS    AND g.t$cpls    =   P.t$cpls and g.comno=@COMNO  and g.t$cpgs is not null
--LEFT  JOIN        TTDSLS033nnn        noPG    WITH(INDEX(IX_T$CPLS_TTDSLS033NNN)) ON  noPg.T$CPLS=com.T$CPLS AND noPG.t$cpgs is null  
Left    JOIN        TTDSLS033nnn        noPG    WITH(INDEX(IX_T$CPLS_TTDSLS033NNN)) on noPG.t$cpgs is null 
        JOIN        TTDUPC001nnn        U   WITH(INDEX(IX_T$ITEM_TTDUPC001NNN),index(ix_comno_TTDUPC001NNN)) ON U.t$item    =   p.t$item    AND U.comno     =   p.Comno
--Limit Items to display based on Price list (introduced on 27th June 09)
        JOIN        ftItemGroupsOfCustomer(@comno,@t$cuno)  pl   ON PL.T$CPGS   =   T.T$CPGS    AND PL.T$CUNO   =   @T$CUNO
                                        AND PL.COMNO        =   @COMNO  
Left    JOIN        TTDSLS031NNN        CPG ON ltrim(rtrim(cpg.t$cpgs)) = pl.t$cpgs and cpg.t$cuno=pl.t$cuno and cpg.comno=pl.comno
        AND         1               =   dbo.fnIsDateInRange(cpg.t$stdt,cpg.t$tdat)

        WHERE               COM.COMNO       =   @COMNO          AND COM.T$CUNO  =   @T$CUNO AND
                            P.t$cpls        =   COM.T$CPLS      AND p.comno     =   @comno      
                    AND     noPg.comno      = @comno            and nopg.t$cpls =   com.t$cpls

                    --noPg.t$cpls       =   com.t$cpls
        AND         1               =   dbo.fnIsDateInRange(p.t$stdt,p.t$tdat)
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE UNSTICK YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY FIRST ?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: WHAT BEARING CAPS LOCK KEY HAS ON THE QUESTION ?!@!@!@ ?

Comment: It's annoying to have to read all caps text. Some people will still help you although you behave this way, hoping that you will better yourself. Others will just disregard you as too annoying to spend their time on.

Comment: All caps is the equivalent of SHOUTING...that's why some people find it inappropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

before performing any more speed tests. Second, use default values to fool the parameter sniffing optimization

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ftItemsOfCustomer](@COMNO CHAR(3) = '020',@T$CUNO CHAR(6) = '000020') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data type of the parameters supposed to be NCHAR or NVARCHAR instead of CHAR and VARCHAR? I've made mistakes like that in the past, where SQL would have to convert the data type, which means an evaluation would occur and indexes would be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for the function if the values come from variables or not. They are only values when they arrive at the function, and the code in the function can't tell the difference even it wanted to.

The result from function calls are cached based on the values of the parameters, which is the likely reason for your result.

If you are calling the function several times with different values, the function will be executed each time. If you are calling the function several times with the same value, the function will only be executed the first time, for the following calls the result will be taken from the cache.

If you run the function twice, first with variables and then with literal values that are the same as in the variables, the function will only run the first time. The second time it will just get the result from the cache, which is of course a lot faster. If you rerun both tests you will get the shorter time for both. If you swap the calls and reruns the test with different values, you will get the opposite times from the first test.

Comment: @Guffa
I ran the function with same variable parameter repeatedly and it takes 9 secs always.
And running same with litaral repeatedly takes 1 sec. Will add the function body to queston.. 
Thanks

Comment: @TonyP: Are you sure that you run the tests with the same values? The code that you posted is full of test code setting different values overriding the original values, and it's not even a function any more as the declaration is commented out...